# Is there any way to perform a cleanup function before the new render on a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

### Description

I have ***SomeComponent*** which uses a some library (we'll call ***domLib***) that mutates the DOM directly (e.g. **modifies** and adds several elements & listeners). ***SomeComponent*** also accepts props ***data*** which ***domlib*** uses

```
const SomeComponent = ({ data }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        domLib.init(data, 'example-container');
        return () => { //cleanup function
            domLib.destroy('example-container'); //removes everything from example-container, listeners etc from example-container
        }
    },[data])
    return (<div id='example-container'>
        <HelpComponent data={data}/>
    </div>)
}
```

***domLib*** must also be able to see/modify ***HelpComponent*** or the children of '*example-container*'

- ***SomeComponent*** accepts the props, ***data***
- A child of ***SomeComponent*** named ***HelpComponent*** uses the prop data
- A library ***domLib*** uses both the ***data*** and ***HelpComponent*** to mutate the DOM (children of the '*example-container*')

### Problem

When receiving new props/updating, since the *cleanup function* runs AFTER render, the `domLib.destroy('example-container');` removes the children of *example-container* which means `<HelpComponent data={data}/>` will also be removed

### Attempts and Issues

```
useEffect(() => {
    domLib.destroy('example-container');
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('example-container'))
    ReactDom.render(<HelpComponent data={data}/>, document.getElementById('example-container'))
    domLib.init(data, 'example-container');
})
return (<div id='example-container'>
    {/* removed */}
</div>)
```

**Attempt**, Create everything inside the **useEffect** hook using **ReactDom** and remove everything I need to right before it.

**Issue**, the render method in `ReactDom.render(<HelpComponent data={data}/>, document.getElementById('example-container'))` does not immediately apply changes to the DOM therefore when ***domLib*** cannot see ***HelpComponent***

**Edit for extra clarity**

The library domLib is [jsPlumb](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb) which I am using to create links between elements. The elements are created based on the data prop, and the lib jsPlumb creates links between those elements.

The issue is the elements created from jsPlumb are outside of the react ecosystem, so it remains between updates, therefore I need to remove them between updates

Answer (score 0):

Add `[]` as a second argument for `useEffect` so it would run once. If you need any props for your lib, add them to watch after changes. Your hook would run only then. For more great information, written by Dan: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/ or docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

EDIT: to watch certain props changes, add them to the square brackets in `useEffect`. An example from the docs:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  [props.source],
);
```

If you want to call destroy method just once, not depending on data changes, do this:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  [],
);
```

Empty function body would do nothing on the first run, but the returned function would run on destroy.

Comment: I forgot to add the [data] as the second arg in my example, however this does not help in any way, first off I NEED it to run again when the props change, also i'm not sure what 'If you need any props for your lib, add them to watch after changes' means

Comment: @steff_bdh I added an update. I would recommend checking the docs, just couple of paragraphs there on the subject of question. Would explain better than I do.

Comment: Thanks however I can't see how limiting my updates helps with cleaning elements that were created outside of React's ecosystem, in this scenario it does not matter whether or not I have an array of dependencies since there is nothing within THIS component that updates the state

Comment: @steff_bdh maybe I didn't understand you then. Do you need to clean `<div id='example-container'>` after every update, but want to preserve `<HelpComponent data={data}/>`? Where does this lib use '`HelpComponent` to mutate the DOM' (you don't pass it anywhere)?

Comment: it uses the children of the container 'example-container', i'll add an edit for clarity, in terms of the desired outcome, 1> old children and artefacts in 'example-container' are removed 2> new children of 'example-container' are created based on new props 3> domLib creates new artefacts and manipulates children of 'example container' the library being used is https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb

Comment: Can you add these two to different subcomponents? So you would not clean this react component entirely. Pass `HelpComponent` it for mutations to the lib with ref reference.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean